# Get ERD from my Redshift database

Tags: aws, erd, redshift

I am a newbie in database management/governance.

**The problem:** I have my companies Postgres RDB in AWS Redshift. So this is not a private project, but enterprise environment. I add new tables/columns, change table names, add new tables quite often so the ERD diagram changes very often. I also have drawn the ERD schematic in draw.io for my collegues who are using SQL queries against the database.
Changing the structure of the database (new/changed table names or column names) means that I have to change each time the schematic drawing of the database for my collegues otherwise they will not be able to use/write their queries. This is a tedious, manual process which consumes a lot of my time.

**Question**: Is there any tool/solution which could make this process automatic? I would be interested in free tools or solutions which I could build myself. I am open to new solutions as well.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Did you heard about https://schemaspy.org? It is not a tipical ERD tool, but you can document your DB with it very fast and it also contain some ERD. Is it enough for your collegues if you generate them a proper documentation? If yes then i will write you a longer answer about this tool.

Comment: Hi I did not but it looks like the tool I need. Can be use on the cloud as well so I can generate an ERD on my Redshift?

Comment: Yes it [supports Redshift](https://schemaspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/databaseType.html#included), so I added an answer with some detailed info. Please accept it if it was that what you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An open-source and free database documenter tool is [schemaspy](https://schemaspy.org/) wich supports plenty of databases. - It's only requires **Java Runtime Environment** on your client machine a **JDBC driver** and a **user with login and read permissions** on your source database.

You can find Amazon Redshift in supported databases [list](https://schemaspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/databaseType.html#included).

To see your database ERD go to [Relationship](https://schemaspy.org/samples/epivirusurf/relationships.html) page:
[image]

You can find [Installation](https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy#installation) and [Quick start](https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy#quick-start) on the GitHub page but here is an example code too:

```bash
java -jar schemaspy.jar \
-t redshift \
-dp jdbc-driver.jar \
-db your_db_name \
-s your_schema \ #[optional]
-host your.host.name.com \ 
-port your_port_num \
-u your_user_name \
-p your_pw \
-o output_folder
```